# Explain your downvoting without comments please

Tags: quality-assurance

Look I know you think you're helping but this practice over the past few weeks (/months) of down voting (and close voting) questions that other long-standing members of the community think are ok is really not helping lately.  this question is an opportunity to talk about it (should be meta but might not be seen).

One thing I don't understand is why not vote close.  Why the down-vote without the close vote.  but why either is the question

Don't worry.  *this* will be deleted within the day

Comment: can you give a few examples of the questions where you see this practice?

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/38869/how-to-set-up-a-testers-guild was the latest example.  I thought Neils is also giving a great answer there and I was surprised at the question down-vote.  Mainly the thing that bugs me is NO EXPLANATION.  If folks would be polite and considerate enough to explain WHY they down-vote it would help people going forward.  Otherwise this is just blind arrows and a system that is not improving quality.

Comment: This should be posted on [meta]. Also note https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/248731.

Comment: down-vote vs the close is a general stackexchange question, although I get your point due to the lower volume of activity here

Comment: move to meta and make it featured?

Comment: I completely agree... although am probably guilty of this myself occasionally! If a question is really badly written or shows no effort, then I'll downvote it thinking that the reason is obvious and so there's no need to leave a comment - forgetting that newcomers may not understand how to use the StackExchange effectively. I like to think we are quite welcoming (especially the veterans), but with 500 avid users and 31,000+ total users, down votes without comments are almost expected.

Comment: Sounds good everyone!  I will now vote to close the question. I am doing this rather than just deleting as some of you may be following it. or it could be moved to meta, don't know how.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be

Comment: Personally, I found downvoting without comment to be rather cowardly.  That's why I bookmarked [I downvoted because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) but I still use it sparingly because sometimes more than one reason applies, but usually I downvote because after a few days, if there's no response from the original poster to my or other comments it aggravates me.  I wish that there was a method of tracking who down or UPvoted posts and answers but I understand why that could have its own set of problems.

Comment: Heh... I upvoted because...

Comment: This can't be migrated to meta as it stands because it isn't in an answerable form. I understand your frustration, but it would be good to explore 1) what is the real problem and 2) what are the solutions to those problems. We might want to explore that on meta, because if it's affecting you, who else might it be effecting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the site itself belong on our Meta site.